# Copy files from NTFS to EXT4

Tags: filesystem, copy

Is there any difference between `cp -r /source /destination` and `cp -a /source /destination` when I am copying from `NTFS` to `EXT4`?

Answer (score 1):

`cp -a` attempts to make copies as close as possible to the source, including metadata and tree information.

`cp -r` recursively copies files and keeps the contents but yields to the user doing the copy for modification times, permissions, and user.

So essentially, just use `cp -a` as it does everything `cp -r` does and more.

[Here is some further reading from the man page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/cp.1.html)

Answer (score 1):

It makes a difference when it comes to links which are located in the source directory.`cp -a` will copy the link as a link. `cp -r` will follow the link, so if the link points to another directory it will copy the contents of the linked directory as well, this can make a huge different in necessary disk space when the linked directory holds a lot of data.

`cp -a` will also preserve file permissions, ownership and timestamps which `cp -r` doesn't. File permissions will be different, even if you copy from an NTFS-formatted partition.